# What is the standard sort order for Python release/version numbers?

Tags: python, easy-install, pip

Python's `pip` and `easy_install` follow some rules to sort packages by their release numbers. What are the rules for numbering beta/release/bugfix releases so these tools will know which is the newest?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a sore point for many folks. `setuptools` and `easy_install` have some rather bizarre rules in an attempt to play nice with everybody. You can read the full rules in `setuptools`'s `parse_version` method, but here's the summary:

- Version numbers are broken up by dots into a tuple of that many segments. 4.5.6.7 is parsed into a tuple equal to `("4", "5", "6", "7")`.
- Trailing zeroes between dashes or alphanumerics are suppressed. 2.4.0 is the same as 2.4; 2.4.05 is the same as 2.4.5.
- Alphanumeric parts are downcased. 2.4.a5 is equal to 2.4.A5.
- Strings that come before "final" alphabetically are assumed to be pre-release versions, so 2.4.5b comes before, not after, 2.4.5.
- Finally, "pre", "preview", and "rc" are treated as if they were "c". The word "dev" is replaced with "@", so that it comes before anything else with the same version. That is, `x.y.z-dev` is guaranteed to come before any other `x.y.z` version.

There are a number of proposals to organize things a bit more, of which the most popular is probably **[PEP 386](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/)**.

Comment: PEP 386 is now accepted and implemented in packaging (Python 3.3 stdlib) and distutils2 (standalone version for 2.4-3.2).

Comment: And PEP 386 was superseded by [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/).

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools?action=highlight&value=setuptools#specifying-your-project-s-version) or look at the source: doc string in pkg_resources.py function parse_version().

Answer (score 2):

Use 1.0a1 and 1.0b2 before 1.0.

The upcoming standard:

- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/#the-new-versioning-algorithm
- http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2009/11/18/distutils-and-distribute-status-part-1/
- http://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutilsversion/

Current setuptools:
http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#specifying-your-project-s-version